# A device repeatedly connects and disconnects when I first start my computer? How can I monitor this to see which device is doing this?

Tags: device-manager

First I suspected that it was a USB device, but I then unplugged all the USB devices(excluding the keyboard and mouse) and it still made the device connect/disconnect sounds repeatedly. I know it wasn't the keyboard or mouse though because I was using them during this time.